# How to close open (deleted) file descriptor on linux shell

Tags: linux, debian, file-descriptor, lsof, openvz

If i use

```
lsof -n | grep deleted
```

I have along list of `php5-fpm` list values.

two sample output of a list value:

```
(deleted)/dev/zero (stat: No such file or directory)

(deleted)/tmp/.ZendSem.JQTejx
```

1) How can i close them within an openVZ container?

2) Is this a result of forgetting to close a mysql handle within a php script?

Comment: The first column of `lsof` output tells you the name of the program that has the file open; the second tells you the PID of that program.

Comment: This looks like a normal behavior for creating temporary files: such file will be automatically deleted by linux kernel when the file is closed.

Comment: the problem  : /var/www/clients/client1/web1/log is 75G and grow up even if i restart the openVZ container

Comment: but the file log size are some MB

Answer (score 0):

```
df -h
```

shows  41% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web1/log
and within the log directory there are only a few MB

so how to restore the lost webspace??